# How can I get "divider" displayed for "nav-pills" and "nav-stacked"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have code something like the following:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#">Available glyphs</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">How to use</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vertical variation</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Single button dropdowns</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checkboxes and radio addons</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Justified</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#">Fixed to bottom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inverted navbar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

class "divider" is not working.  Am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/B9gHc

Comment: Is `divider` a Bootstrap class? If not, what's your CSS?

Comment: it is Bootstrap class

Comment: What I mean is, does Bootstrap apply it to navs? I don't see that they do. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `divider` class has changed to `nav-divider` in Bootstrap 3..

```
 <li class="nav-divider"></li>
```

So you can use this without any custom CSS. http://bootply.com/101379

**UPDATE**

`.nav-divider` has been deprecated in v3.0.1

Comment: Unfortunately `.nav-divider` [has been deprecated from v3.0.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/a5f5954268779ce0faf7607b3c35191a8d0fdfe6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_navs.scss#L54) and so at some point it will cease to work. You can still use `.divider` with  dropdown menus, but I think that's it.

Comment: @Skelly Could you please update this answer to reflect [the deprecation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/56c8826c770376840d1873f4e524f096ab5c686d)?

Comment: It was correct at the time, and that's why I updated it to say `.nav-divider` has been depracated.

Comment: Also remember about role="separator" attribute

Comment: @Sielu So you're downvoting because there is no role="separator" attribute??

Answer (score 2):

`<li class="nav-item"><hr style="width:90%;"></li>`

Because of the deprecation. Change according to your liking.